# Using index.php to manage all url paths in my site

Tags: php, url, path

I must be missing something obvious, since this seems like it shouldn't be a difficult problem.  I want all url paths on my site (`http://example.com`, `http://example.com/admin`, `http://example.com/happy/happy/joy/joy`, etc.) to be handled through my index.php.  I've seen this done before, but offhand I do not know how to do it.

Comment: If you are using Apache, a rule in your .htaccess file using mod_rewrite will do it.

Comment: Agree with Borealid you can't do this without the help of your web server. Depending on the flavour of server will depend on how you go about it. For example, see [Zend Framework web server configuration](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/project-structure.rewrite.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create an `.htaccess` file in your root directory with this :

```
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Base directory
RewriteBase /

# Protect hidden files from being viewed
<Files .*>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny From All
</Files>

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]
```

Apache flags explained :

`[L]` - Alias for "Last", instructs the server that the rewrite rules have come to an end and it's time to perform an internal redirection without changing the browser's uri.

`[PT]` - Alias for "Pass Through", allows a Mod_Rewrite manipulated uri to be passed to the next type of handler, accordingly to the php.ini module's order of inclusion. Usefull depending on the subject.

Comment: Drupal appears to use `RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]`.  What is the difference?

Comment: Check the updated post. There's no need for the `L` flag in your case, since what you want is to rewrite browser's uri.

Comment: Handler?  Does that mean another RewriteRule in turn?

Comment: No, `PT` will force the uri to be passed as an argument / handler to the next module.

Comment: So without it, other modules aren't able to get the changed URI..?  Is this a kind of imperative programming going on within the config file?

Comment: For example, suppose you want to run `Mod_Alias` on a certain set of uri's, but not all .. there you go :) it's optional, as the module itself.